# iOS 8 re-order control with transparent background

Tags: ios, uitableview

In new iOS 8 has re-order control transparent background, while moving. I'm not doing any fancy stuff with tableview, just setting indentWhileEditing false and editing style none. My tableview has transparent background and behind tableview is imageview with image. How can I set background for re-order control, so it is not trasnparent?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just updated description. I dont know how to make this reorder control not transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The reordering control is positioned automatically by the `UITableView` in the `accessoryView`, directly from the documentation:

> The reordering control is gray, multiple horizontal bar control on the right side of the cell. Users can drag this control to reorder the cell within the table. The default value is NO. If the value is YES , the reordering control temporarily replaces any accessory view.

Unfortunately there is no public API to customize the reordering control itself. However since you want to modify just the backgroundColor of the accessoryView, your best bet is to modify the cell background. Something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = yourColor;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an image of what you see?